# Need some help translating a get value in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement

Our school receives data from a source during a sync.

I'm familiar with JavaScript but would like to ask for a litle help before I make a change.

Here is the scenario: The source sending the information to us has the default value as "tobedeleted". We need this to be translated to "inactivate". and then put into our DB.

What's being sent I think is simply ignored because it doesn't match any of our enum values.

My idea is to get help writing: if the get value = "tobedeleted" then translate it to "inactivate" and then update our database.

```
    {
      "path": "/v1/courses/{course_id}/enrollments/{id}",
      "description": "Conclude, deactivate, or delete an enrollment. If the +task+ argument isn't given, the enrollment\nwill be concluded.",
      "operations": [
        {
          "method": "DELETE",
          "summary": "Conclude, deactivate, or delete an enrollment",
          "notes": "Conclude, deactivate, or delete an enrollment. If the +task+ argument isn't given, the enrollment\nwill be concluded.",
          "nickname": "conclude_deactivate_or_delete_enrollment",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "paramType": "path",
              "name": "course_id",
              "description": "ID",
              "type": "string",
              "format": null,
              "required": true,
              "deprecated": false
            },
            {
              "paramType": "path",
              "name": "id",
              "description": "ID",
              "type": "string",
              "format": null,
              "required": true,
              "deprecated": false
            },
            {
              "paramType": "query",
              "name": "task",
              "description": "The action to take on the enrollment.\nWhen inactive, a user will still appear in the course roster to admins, but be unable to participate.\n(\"inactivate\" and \"deactivate\" are equivalent tasks)",
              "type": "string",
              "format": null,
              "required": false,
              "deprecated": false,
              "enum": [
                "conclude",
                "delete",
                "inactivate",
                "deactivate"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "response_fields": [

          ],
          "deprecated": false,
          "deprecation_description": "",
          "type": "Enrollment"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you receive data from x and then you need to take that data (maybe modify it) and send it to a different database?

Comment: Yes.  I believe that is how this is working.  We receive a value from X and need to update Y (with a different value then what X sent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assign the JSON to a variable named **data**. Then you can do

```
   data.operations.map((operation) => {
    if (operation.method === 'DELETE') {
        operation.parameters.map((param, queryIndex) => {
            if (param.paramType === 'query') {
                param.enum.map((item, enumIndex) => {
                    if (item === 'tobedeleted') {
                        operation.parameters[queryIndex].enum[enumIndex] = 'inactivate';
                        //item = 'inactivate';
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return operation;
});
```

Note: This may not be an optimized code but it does the work.

Comment: That script looks perfect.  Forgive my ignorance.  Where you have written "item" is that exactly what you suggest ("item") or should I be looking for a different term / variable?  This file is 1400 line plus.

Comment: Sorry Anthony I didnt get your question

Comment: You  need to simplify the data. You need to figure it out in which case you are getting this particular value you are searching for .As i can see from the json when paramType is Query  pick that particular block and modify.

Comment: No you cant add anything like that to the JSON. I will try to edit my code snippet

Comment: I posted a link to the file.  I simply just do not know where in the file (line number) to place the script.  I fear messing up the rest of the code based on placement.

http://freedomcheck.com/enrollments.json

Comment: Its a documentation. Firstly you cannot add any script to JSON. The code i have written is simple JS. It can be used in the place where you are trying to fetch the response and modify the response.